# Replace NaNs of a categorical variable by grouping them with respect to continuous variable

Tags: python, pandas, nan, continuous, dtype

I'm facing problem while grouping the 'Weather cond' based on 'temperature' as it is a continuous variable. So, I need it to be grouped by converting 'temperature' to `int64` and then replacing *(*by mode*)* NaNs of '`Weather cond`'. But it should not convert the original 'temperature' to `int64`.

Df is:

```
temperature weather cond
    0   25.6    Cloudy
    1   28.7    Sunny
    2   26.9    NaN
    3   25.9    Cloudy
    4   29.9    Cloudy
    5   28.1    Overcast
    6   34.7    Sunny
    7   29.6    NaN
    8   26.6    NaN
    9   20.5    NaN
```

*Explanation:*

If we consider the temperatures 28.7 and 28.1, these values should be converted to 28 (*not in original df*) and then fill the NaNs with the mode of 'Weather cond' representing those temperatures.

*Note: Even approximation(floor/ceil) also accepted i.e considering 28.7 as 29 and 28.1 as 28.*

Comment: Sunny has 1 34, and 1 28. How are you determining mode in this case.

Comment: Also what do you mean replace by mode? The modes are `'Cloudy' -> 25, 'Overcast' -> 28, 'Sunny' -> 28/34` But the missing values are `26,29,26,20` So how does the mapping occur?

Comment: @HenryEcker Here I'm going with mode because weather condition is not fixed for a particular temperature, it can vary.

Comment: @HenryEcker You can use nearer temperatures to deal, if some weather conditions  don't have any temperatures.

Comment: so you want to fill the NaN of weather condition with the values of mode of temperature?

Comment: @AnuragDabas No, weather conditions can be grouped by the similar temperatures and then NaNs should be filled by 'mode of weather conition'

Comment: @jezrael Can you help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

- self merge with [merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.0/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html)

```
import io
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""temperature  weather cond
    0   25.6    Cloudy
    1   28.7    Sunny
    2   26.9    NaN
    3   25.9    Cloudy
    4   29.9    Cloudy
    5   28.1    Overcast
    6   34.7    Sunny
    7   29.6    NaN
    8   26.6    NaN
    9   20.5    NaN"""), sep="\s\s+", engine="python")

pd.merge_asof(df.sort_values("temperature"), 
              df.loc[~df["weather cond"].isna()].sort_values("temperature"), 
              on="temperature", 
              direction="nearest")
```

|  | temperature | weather cond_x | weather cond_y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 20.5 | nan | Cloudy |
| 1 | 25.6 | Cloudy | Cloudy |
| 2 | 25.9 | Cloudy | Cloudy |
| 3 | 26.6 | nan | Cloudy |
| 4 | 26.9 | nan | Cloudy |
| 5 | 28.1 | Overcast | Overcast |
| 6 | 28.7 | Sunny | Sunny |
| 7 | 29.6 | nan | Cloudy |
| 8 | 29.9 | Cloudy | Cloudy |
| 9 | 34.7 | Sunny | Sunny |